# I can't do dispatch inside useEffect - React + Redux + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I need to make the dispatch inside the useEffect but I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the
> body of a function component. This can happen for one of the following
> reasons
>
> 1. You may have versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) that don't match.
> 2. You could be breaking hook rules.
> 3. You may have more than one copy of React in the same application. See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips on how to
>    debug and fix this problem.

If I remove the dispatch outside of the useEffect, no error pops.
I don't know how to fix this as when I have done something similar in JS I have not had the same thing happen.
Any suggestions on how to fix it?

My component:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { fetchGetPosts } from "../features/thunks/fetchGetPosts";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../hooks/redux-hooks";
import { GridCard } from "./GridCard";

export const Grid = () => {

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch;

  const postsList = useAppSelector((state) => state.posts.posts);

   useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(fetchGetPosts());
   }, [dispatch]);


  return (
    <>
      <div className="grid">
        <div className="grid__container">
          <GridCard />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

redux-hooks.ts:

```
import { AsyncThunkAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { useSelector, useDispatch, TypedUseSelectorHook } from "react-redux";
import { AppDispatch, RootState } from "../store/store";

export const useAppDispatch = (arg: AsyncThunkAction<void, void, {}>) => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

store.ts:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import postsSlice from "../features/postsSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsSlice,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({ serializableCheck: false }),
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Comment: The way you've configured your `useAppDispatch`, it is actually a generator for a `useDispatch` hook.  Change your component to `const dispatch = useAppDispatch();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see

```
export const useAppDispatch = (arg: AsyncThunkAction<void, void, {}>) => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

**useAppDispatch** **is a function**

So you have to do

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
```

Comment: You are right... I hadn't noticed that detail. Thank you! :)